# Setting Correct Solution In A Genetic Algorithm Initialization

Tags: genetic-algorithm

Please I'm using a genetic algorithm to find a solution to a problem, how can you write your initialization function without knowing what the final solution will be?
For example I am working on an interior design project using AR that makes use of a GA to generate the best arrangement of the furniture in the room.
In other GAs I've come across, the correct solution is supplied to the initialization function so that the GA can work towards it.
In this case where I don't know what the best arrangement should be since the algorithm makes use of certain interior design guidelines, how can write my initialization function without it.
Can I just initialize the size of the population without giving the algorithm knowledge of what to work towards?

Comment: Your initialization function can be randomly generated arrangements (keeping constraints e.g, the furniture shouldn't overlap with themselves and the walls), and you need a way to evaluate an arrangement, a function which returns a value of how good the arrangement is, the GA can work towards improving this value.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gc7__

Answer (score 0):

Your initialization function can be randomly generated arrangements (keeping constraints e.g, the furniture shouldn't overlap with themselves and the walls), and you need a way to evaluate an arrangement, a function which returns a value of how good the arrangement is, the GA can work towards improving this value.